# Expansion of Gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If we have a gas that expands at a constant heat capacity, and it does work, how can we express the heat transfer in terms of work done by the gas? Should we simply rely on the second law of thermodynamics? Or is there another way of writing an expression for the heat transfer?

Comment: Conservation of Energy (i.e. the first law) is the relevant principle here. X Joules of work have been transferred out of the gas, where did that energy come from?

Comment: Did you mean constant internal energy (temperature)?  Isn't the work equal to the integral of PdV?

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by  "heat capacity", since the term is sometimes confused with specific heat.